# AWS lambda function for s3 upload - Python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-lambda

I am have written some code in Python for my Lambda function. This should take the CSV data from the url and should upload/put it in one of the s3 bucket in same aws account. All policies and IAM role has been set but still lambda is not performing it's task. The code is below. Can someone please check the code and let me know the error.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import boto3
import os
import time

BUCKET_NAME = '***'

CSV_URL = 'http://***'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = urlopen(CSV_URL)
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.upload_fileobj(response, BUCKET_NAME,time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
    response.close()
```

I have attached the following policy to my lambda function apart from the basic execution.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::**",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*/*"
            ]
       }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide some more information. How is your lambda invoked (direct invocation, by another AWS service)? What do see in the invocation and/or CloudWatch logs?

Comment: Lambda will be invoked by the CloudWatch Event. It has to perform the task every night and required settings are in place.

Comment: What happens if you directly invoke the lambda using the CLI: `aws lambda invoke ...`?

Comment: Thats what I am trying it via "TEST" from the console but it throws an error "task timed out"

Comment: "Task timed out" means that your function takes longer than the timeout you configured for it. By default this is set to 3 seconds. Try increasing the timeout. How big is your CSV file? Maybe it takes too long to download/upload it. Also, is your function running in a VPC and you forgot adding access to the internet (assuming your CSV file is available somewhere on the internet) ?

Comment: I increased the time for 90 secs and I am able to access the url through my lambda function. Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: I have attached the following policy to my lambda function apart from the basic execution. {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::******",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}